# Ways of ensuring parameters 'sum to one' during function minimisation

Tags: python, minimization, chi-squared

I'm trying to perform a minimisation where some parameters must sum to one using [PyMinuit](http://code.google.com/p/pyminuit/). I'm wondering if there is a standard method of implementing this kind of thing?

Is it usual to set the function to some large value if the constraint is not met?
e.g.

```
def f(params):
    if params.sum() != 1:
        return 1e6
    else:
        ... compute actual value ...
```

Is it a very bad idea to normalise the parameters each round? e.g.

```
if params.sum() != 1:
    for param in params:
        param = param / params.sum()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to alter things so that the constraint is baked in to your minimization. Without some more details about what you're doing, exactly, I'd try introducing a [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). It's a pretty common thing to do in a freshman calculus course, so you should be able to find lots of examples online.

PS: Are you using PyMinuit because you're doing particle physics?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll see if I can get Lagrange multipliers into the minimisation. The biggest problem I can see with doing it this way in my code is that the function `f` will be generated behind the scenes and passed to the minimisation routine. I think `SymPy` may be quite useful for getting the derivative at run-time though. P.S. I am doing particle physics, but the problem is based in nuclear. ;)

Comment: Yeah I was trying to think how you'd manage to minimize something with constraints NOT using Lagrange multipliers.